# Merge arbitrary number of xts objects of different lengths by index

Tags: r, merge, xts

I'd like to merge 3 xts objects of different lengths into one xts with 3 columns and indexed by the first xts object's dates.

```
a_xts <- xts(4:10, Sys.Date()+4:10)
b_xts <- xts(c(7:12), Sys.Date()+4:9)
c_xts <- xts(15:18, Sys.Date()+4:7)
```

I'd like to preserve a_xts index dates. The merged xts should look like:

```
           a_xts b_xts c_xts
2021-03-05     4     7    15
2021-03-06     5     8    16
2021-03-07     6     9    17
2021-03-08     7    10    18
2021-03-09     8    11    NA
2021-03-10     9    12    NA
2021-03-11    10    NA    NA
```

My solution is to merge each one by one making a new xts object for each addition:

```
ab_xts <- merge(a_xts,b_xts, all = c(TRUE,FALSE))
abc_xts <- merge(ab_xts, c_xts, all = c(TRUE,FALSE))
```

Is there a better way to do this without converting to .zoo and back to .xts objects?

**Edit**

when merging all xts objects, I'd like to keep only the rows that match the index dates for a_xts without adding any additional index dates. For example:

```
d_xts <- xts(c(7:18), Sys.Date()+4:15
```

d_xts has greater length than a_xts, while b_xts and c_xts are less. Continuing my solution by adding xts objects one by one gets me there but seems inefficient.

```
> abcd_xts <- merge(abc_xts, d_xts, all = c(TRUE,FALSE))
> abcd_xts
           a_xts b_xts c_xts d_xts
2021-03-05     4     7    15     7
2021-03-06     5     8    16     8
2021-03-07     6     9    17     9
2021-03-08     7    10    18    10
2021-03-09     8    11    NA    11
2021-03-10     9    12    NA    12
2021-03-11    10    NA    NA    13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following (although for the specific example in the question the [...] is not needed).

```
merge(a_xts, b_xts, c_xts)[time(a_xts), ]
```

giving:

```
           a_xts b_xts c_xts
2021-03-05     4     7    15
2021-03-06     5     8    16
2021-03-07     6     9    17
2021-03-08     7    10    18
2021-03-09     8    11    NA
2021-03-10     9    12    NA
2021-03-11    10    NA    NA
```

Comment: As my edit explains, I need only the rows containing `a_xts` index dates. This solution will add index dates when adding an xts object with a greater length than `a_xts`.

Comment: Use `merge(a_xts, b_xts, c_xts)[time(a_xts), ]`  (although in the example in the question it makes no difference).

Comment: `merge(a_xts, b_xts, c_xts)[time(a_xts), ]` works. Can you post answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 0):

We can place it in a `list` and use `merge` with `Reduce`

```
out <- Reduce(merge, mget(ls(pattern = '_xts$')))
colnames(out) <- paste0(letters[1:3], "_xts")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that `merge()` can left outer join on **multiple** xts objects with argument `all = c(TRUE,FALSE)`. This matches only the rows from the first xts passed to `merge()`.

```
> merge(a_xts,b_xts,c_xts,d_xts, all = c(TRUE,FALSE))

                   a_xts b_xts c_xts d_xts
        2021-03-05     4     7    15     7
        2021-03-06     5     8    16     8
        2021-03-07     6     9    17     9
        2021-03-08     7    10    18    10
        2021-03-09     8    11    NA    11
        2021-03-10     9    12    NA    12
        2021-03-11    10    NA    NA    13
```